# How to successfully Sync the build.gradle file?

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

[image: I am trying to add plugin id for Dagger Hilt in my app/build.gradle file. I am getting this error every time I try to Sync it]

This is the image of my Log file that is showing me the error , when i try to remove the line no 10 and 11, the error goes.

Comment: a) The message tells you to use only ìd`- why do you use then `kotlin` in line 10 instead? Should this be the same as line 5 `id 'kotlin-kapt'`?
b) You should only have one plugins block in your `build.gradle`

Comment: I removed the 'kotlin("kapt")' and simply added id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin") to first plugin block and now it got synced successfully. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'll duplicate the comment to the answer section, so that others will find it.

Answer (score 1):

a) The message tells you to use only `id- why do you use then kotlin` in line 10 instead? Should this be the same as line 5 id 'kotlin-kapt'?
b) You should only have one plugins block in your build.gradle